# Something wrong with my computer

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, desktop-computer, gaming

Im having problems with my PC for weeks ago. Since the problem starts im getting like lag or low frame rating (20FPS even playing low requirements games like LoL or Borderlands) but Windows Task Manager say that all resource's use are low, CPU 9-10%, memory 20-25%, GPU like 10-15%. I looked for a virus, I formated Windows (thrice), I checked that I have actualized drivers, I removed GPU and installed it again, tried to play offline in case the internet its the problem, but everything remains and I dont even know what to try cause I dont know if is GPU problem, hardware, software, memory or what, so any suggest or help is appreciated.

**Technical information**:

- Intel Core i7-6700k
- 16GB RAM DDR4
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 1080 8GB
- Windows 10 Pro

If you need more info just ask.

Comment: Do you have Gaming mode enabled in Settings / Gaming? On some PCs, it claims to work wonders, when on others it just hinders instead of helping, but it's kinda hit-or-miss. One thing you didn't mention in your hardware description is the size and definition of your screen or screens when you play. That could be a factor.

Comment: Have you checked the temps? If something is overheating the speed will be throttled.

Comment: Hi @Didier, the screen its 27' adn definition 2K, but all works fine for years (the PC have like 3 years) and suddenly from one day to next it start to get strange. I will see the Gaming mode that u mention, maybe its something bad configured.

Comment: HHi @Appleoddity the temp are all lows, CPU always like 26-30º and graphic card like 35º-45ºC when playing. I even played at summer and it never goes behind 55º.

Comment: I hadn't realized you had a desktop PC. Have you checked the cables between PC and monitor, and power source and monitor, if there is one? One loose cable, and your whole experience is shot...

Comment: monitor works fine, the problem its in the PC cause its getting laggy sometimes even charging applications or webs, like was hard to charge textures or managing memories or idk....but dont know how to detect the problem,everything looks like working fine with GPU, Nvidia control panel all correct, all drivers updated (last night have another one update). Its any application or web or idk to detect internal hardware errors? Like burned diode or resistance...thought that motherboard should detect that, it have error panel for that but...i dont know :S

Comment: do u have LEAGUE DISPLAYS in ur pc?

Comment: @DarkBeccio no but could do some, i can play now at 25-40fps more or less stable except when have more elements on screen (like rain, or near the nexus with more minions and champs). Its probable that its GPU problem, but cant find anything. When the quarantine ends will try to change it for a friends one to see if works, but need something to find the exact problem so i could try to fix it.

Comment: @PRM i asked because i had the exact same problem and in my case was league displays. I tried everything and just by luck i found out what the problem was. can u tell me the last windows 10 update u did?? and if possible u should run gpu-z and post the screen.

Comment: @DarkBeccio last Win10 Update is KB4497165 (if clic search updates, it say its the last one) and the gpu-z screen:
First screen  :  http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/20/05/23/sb5.png
Sensors  :  http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/20/05/23/vg2.png
Actually league is the only game i can play more or less, but its impossible to play Terraria, Borderlands or whatever i tried. If need more screens from gpu-z (its 11 screens in advanced with DirectX 9, 10 etc) i can put they too.

Comment: @PRM gpu look fine, this has to be somehow software related. have u tried uninstall the last update?  windows 10 update sometimes cause fps drop.

Comment: @DarkBeccio i formated clean Windows 3-4 times, i can try to unistall the update. Btw, i played one fast bot game in league with open gpu-z, this is the link with the MAX readings http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/20/05/23/w4q.png

Comment: @PRM the card is in idle state it means it has poor work to do.  this is strange, in nvdia control panel under manage 3d settings check if power management mode is prefer maximum performance. Is it possible that the problem is the nvidia driver at this point

Comment: @DarkBeccio i changed the power management option, restarted and nothing changed, but today it have little moments of "normal working" (League at 220fps like half game, then 40-45fps) so i open again gpu-z during the game to see if its something different   http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/20/05/24/z6y.png

Comment: @DarkBeccio it was working fine yesterday, today again its broken, and the gpuz its near exact numbers. tried to reinstalla driver but nothing change.